# Error: (4025) Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "_SYSTEMTIME", expected "TSystemTime"

Tags: delphi-7, lazarus, freepascal

I had such a problem with TSystemTime! There is a project in Delphi 7 that works great! I translate this program into Android, so the choice fell on Lazarus, since it has the ability to program under the platform I need.

When I started to run the program under Android, the compiler began to swear on Windows.pas which is used there. I sawed it out completely and just added the type, const, procedure, function I needed to the project and here the most interesting thing began ...

Here is the part of the code where the errors are:

```
 function NowUTC: TDateTime;
var
  st: TSystemTime;
begin
  Uninit(st);
  GetSystemTime(st);
  result := SystemTimeToDateTime(st); //error
end;

function UtcToLocal(utcTime: TDateTime): TDateTime;
var
  st: TSystemTime;
  lt: TSystemTime;
begin
  DateTimeToSystemTime(utcTime, st);  <- error
  Uninit(lt);
  SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(nil, st, lt);
  result := SystemTimeToDateTime(lt);  <- error
end;
function LocalToUTC(localTime: TDateTime): TDateTime;
var
  inverseTZ: TTimeZoneInformation;
  st: TSystemTime;
  ut: TSystemTime;
begin
  DateTimeToSystemTime(localTime, st);  <- error
  Uninit(inverseTZ);
  GetTimezoneInformation(inverseTZ);
  inverseTZ.Bias := -inverseTZ.Bias;
  inverseTZ.DaylightBias := -inverseTZ.DaylightBias;
  Uninit(ut);
  SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(@inverseTZ, st, ut);
  result := SystemTimeToDateTime(ut);  <- error
end;

function UtcDateTimeToFiletime(utcDateTime: TDateTime): TFileTime;
var
  st: TSystemTime;
begin
  DateTimeToSystemTime(utcDateTime, st); <- error
  Uninit(result);
  SystemTimeToFileTime(st, result);
end; 

function FileTimeToLocalDateTime(const ft: TFileTime): TDateTime;
var
  st: TSystemTime;
  lft: TFileTime;
begin
  Uninit(lft);
  FileTimeToLocalFileTime(ft, lft);
  Uninit(st);
  FileTimeToSystemTime(lft, st);
  result := SystemTimeToDateTime(st); <- error
end;
```

And the compiler shows such errors:

```
Error: (4025) Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "_SYSTEMTIME", expected "TSystemTime"
Error: (3069) Call by var for arg no. 2 has to match exactly: Got "_SYSTEMTIME" expected "TSystemTime"
Error: (4025) Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "_SYSTEMTIME", expected "TSystemTime"
Error: (3069) Call by var for arg no. 2 has to match exactly: Got "_SYSTEMTIME" expected "TSystemTime"
Error: (4025) Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "_SYSTEMTIME", expected "TSystemTime"
Error: (3069) Call by var for arg no. 2 has to match exactly: Got "_SYSTEMTIME" expected "TSystemTime"
Error: (4025) Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "_SYSTEMTIME", expected "TSystemTime"
```

Here is the type I use:

```
{TSystemTime}
  { System time is represented with the following structure: }
  PSystemTime = ^TSystemTime;
  _SYSTEMTIME = record
    wYear: Word;
    wMonth: Word;
    wDayOfWeek: Word;
    wDay: Word;
    wHour: Word;
    wMinute: Word;
    wSecond: Word;
    wMilliseconds: Word;
  end;
  {$EXTERNALSYM _SYSTEMTIME}
  TSystemTime = _SYSTEMTIME; 
  SYSTEMTIME = _SYSTEMTIME;
  {$EXTERNALSYM SYSTEMTIME}
```

In the type it is written that it is the same (TSystemTime = _SYSTEMTIME) Help please understand. Well and in addition procedure, function which I took from Windows.pas, can helps ...

```
procedure GetSystemTime(var lpSystemTime: TSystemTime); stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM GetSystemTime}
procedure GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(var lpSystemTimeAsFileTime: TFileTime); stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM GetSystemTimeAsFileTime}
function SetSystemTime(const lpSystemTime: TSystemTime): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM SetSystemTime}
procedure GetLocalTime(var lpSystemTime: TSystemTime); stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM GetLocalTime}
function SetLocalTime(const lpSystemTime: TSystemTime): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM SetLocalTime}
function GetSystemTimeAdjustment(var lpTimeAdjustment, lpTimeIncrement: DWORD;
  var lpTimeAdjustmentDisabled: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM GetSystemTimeAdjustment}
function SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(lpTimeZoneInformation: PTimeZoneInformation;
  var lpUniversalTime, lpLocalTime: TSystemTime): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime}
function GetTimeZoneInformation(var lpTimeZoneInformation: TTimeZoneInformation): DWORD; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM GetTimeZoneInformation}
function SetTimeZoneInformation(const lpTimeZoneInformation: TTimeZoneInformation): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM SetTimeZoneInformation}
function SystemTimeToFileTime(const lpSystemTime: TSystemTime; var lpFileTime: TFileTime): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM SystemTimeToFileTime}
function FileTimeToLocalFileTime(const lpFileTime: TFileTime; var lpLocalFileTime: TFileTime): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM FileTimeToLocalFileTime}
function LocalFileTimeToFileTime(const lpLocalFileTime: TFileTime; var lpFileTime: TFileTime): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM LocalFileTimeToFileTime}
function FileTimeToSystemTime(const lpFileTime: TFileTime; var lpSystemTime: TSystemTime): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM FileTimeToSystemTime}
procedure OutputDebugString(lpOutputString: PChar); stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM OutputDebugString}
```

Comment: Even if you can get the code to compile, it won't work on Android since the code is using Windows-specific functionality. You need to re-write the code to either 1) use IFDEFs for platform-specific functions, or 2) use cross-platform functions. And BTW, if you upgrade to Delphi XE6 or later, it supports Android as a target platform. Delphi 7 is for Windows only.

Comment: You can't use Windows API calls on Android, even if you redeclare the types yourself. Windows calls are not available on Android. You can't pretend they are when they don't exist. Delphi calls the underlying OS functions from Windows, and you can't simply redeclare them and use them when the underlying OS functions don't exist on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't post anything compilable (missing using clauses etc), so the first step would to throw all this away and reduce the problem to something minimal.

That said however, if you declare tsystemtime yourself, and then pass it to a windows unit routine that expects the type declared in the windows unit, then no wonder that it doesn't work.